Git Changes In Forked Branch Merge Into Original Branch
I have a branch in original_repo.
Someone forked this repository and called their new repository forked_repo.
In both repositories, I have a branch called branch_a.
How do I take the changes from forked_repo 's branch_a and merge them into original_repo 's branch_a?

To merge changes from the branch_a of the forked_repo into the branch_a:
1.Add the Forked Repository as a Remote: git remote add forked_repo <forked_repo_url>
2.Fetch the Changes from the Forked Repository: git fetch forked_repo
3.Checkout the Branch_a in the Original Repository: git checkout branch_a
4.Merge Changes: git merge forked_repo/branch_a
5.Push Changes: git push origin branch_a
